# Want to display the value of function in a tkinter label

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to return the result of my function in a tkinter label instead of just printing the function result in the interpreter, I'm unable to do this, please help. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
top_widget=Tk()
top_widget.geometry('400x120+650+300')
top_widget.title('Calculate HCF- Arjit')

label1=Label(top_widget,text='Enter First Number',bg='gold',fg='blue').place(x=25,y=25)
label2=Label(top_widget,text='Enter Second Number',bg='gold',fg='blue').place(x=25,y=55)

box1=Entry(top_widget)
box2=Entry(top_widget)

box1.focus()

box1.place(x=155,y=25)
box2.place(x=155,y=55)

def HCF():
    small_number=int(box1.get())
    big_number=int(box2.get())
    mylis=[]
    mtlist=[]
    for i in range(1,small_number+1):
       if small_number%i==0:
           mylis.append(i)
    for j in range(1,big_number+1):
       if big_number%j==0:
           mtlist.append(j)
    myasd=[]
    for c in range(len(mylis)):
       if mylis[c] in mtlist:
           myasd.append(mylis[c])
    print(myasd[-1])

btn=Button(top_widget,text='HCF',command=HCF).place(x=170,y=75)
top_widget.mainloop()
```

Comment: *"I'm unable to do this"* - so what happens instead? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected baheviour (what did you think would happen, and what happens instead)? Could you reduce your code to a [minimal example](http://sscce.org) that displays the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.  Create a label to display your output text by adding these lines near the top:

```
label3=Label(top_widget,text='Enter Second Number',bg='gold',fg='blue')
label3.place(x=25,y=85)
```

2. At the end of the `HCF` function, instead of

```
print(myasd[-1])
```

set the label text:

```
label3.config(text=myasd[-1])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working. Can you suggest internet resources on learning tkinter